# FCM is not receiving in iphone 8 foreground mode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM is receiving correctly with ios 10 devices in both foreground and background condition, But in case of iphone 8 (ios 11.2) FCM is receiving in background mode.  Appdelegate contains

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[messageKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print("fcm-->\(userInfo)")

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option


    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active { // In iOS 10 if app is in foreground do nothing.
        completionHandler([])
    }



    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: messageKey), object: nil,userInfo: userInfo)
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[messageKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print("fcm-->1\(userInfo)")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: messageKey), object: nil,userInfo: userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    updateGCMIdInServer(fcmToken)

}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message 10 +: \(remoteMessage)")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: messageKey), object: nil, userInfo: remoteMessage.appData)
}

}
```

But not reaching the notification observer function. Help me with passing the data to specific viewcontroller from appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

It may be helped you-

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        //From here we will navigate to other screens:-


        print("User Info : \(userInfo)")

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        //completionHandler([])
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
    }
```

Comment: i have these code to in my appdelegate i will edit my question

Comment: fcm is working perfectly in iphone 6 (ios 11.2) but not in iphone 8

Comment: Actually I was faced same issue, I just replaced completionHandler([]) to  **completionHandler([.alert,.sound])**

Comment: One more thing, Update your pod for Firebase, Most probably issue is occurring because of that.

Comment: any specific version ?

Comment: No, Just update pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

Comment: Make sure, dont update other pods library, May be they affect your project, Means Depcicated situation

Comment: if i change completionHandler([]) to this completionHandler([.alert,.sound])  what difference will happen to the code

Comment: I was not receiving Notification in background than I add this Than its worked perfect

Comment: i have using xcode 8 and swift 3   'pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
 post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
         end
     end
 end
end'

Comment: and this was the result     
Using Firebase (4.8.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.5)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.13)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.8)
Using FirebaseMessaging (2.0.8)

Comment: Hi, I was on leave. Did you fix your issue

Comment: i have managaed to get fcm in background mode but when app is in foreground mode i dont no where to post the notification please healp

Comment: Just replace - **completionHandler([])** to **completionHandler([.alert,.sound])**

Comment: In my device (iPhone 6s) i am able to read the FCM message in both Forground and Backgound mode but when i send a testflight its not working in iPhone 8 in forground mode. FCM is delivering properly but i dont from where i can read or post the notification data to my viewcontroller

Comment: Did you receive notification in 6s after downloading it from Testflight?

Comment: Please confirm the os for both, iPhone 6s and iPhone 8(on which notification not received)

Comment: in iphone 8 background notifications are receiving , foreground notification are not receiving